# SwiftUI List with alternate background colors

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui, background-color

In SwiftUI, `UITableView` is replaced with `List`.

Is there a way to alternate the background colors of the list's cells/rows?

I would like to implement something like this:

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) { 
    aCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0) 
}
```

See article https://medium.com/@ronm333/improving-the-appearance-of-ios-tableviews-9effb7184efb for a good example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use something along these lines to alternate list background colours in my SwiftUI lists

```
List {
    ForEach(items.indices) { index in
        Text(items[index])
            .listRowBackground((index  % 2 == 0) ? Color(.systemBlue) : Color(.white))
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this solution has an Apple bug if you have a segmented control:
"count (7) != its initial count (10). `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data."

Comment: Interestingly, this only works if I include the `ForEach { … }`

Comment: this gives the ```"Non-constant range: not an integer range"``` warning and works ```only``` with indices not with an enumerated array but adding ```id``` to loop like here ```ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self)``` would fix the problem

Answer (score 21):

SwiftUI now supports this on macOS Monterey through [`inset(alternatesRowBackgrounds:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/insettablestyle/inset(alternatesrowbackgrounds:)).

`.listStyle(.inset(alternatesRowBackgrounds: true))`